# meteor android cordova: Empty tiles with openlayers basemap

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, openlayers, openlayers-3

I have a meteor app with an openlayers OSM map that works fine in all browsers. However, I have the following problem when I build an android cordova app with it:

The map tiles are empty (white background). Only the vector features show up in the app.

Has anybody ever built a meteor app for android that includes openlayers?

Comment: I have build one, and it seems to be working properly with OSM on Android. You can try to inspect it with Chrome.

Comment: it works properly on android chrome. The problem only occurs when I run the app (apk)

Comment: You can inspect the app using chrome over ADB. Connect your device and use `chorme://inspect` to have the chrome dev tools connect to the webview on the Android device.

Comment: oh, ok... i'll give it a try tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @MasterAM I just gave it a try. I can debug all tabs in android chrome, but the webviews are not available in the inspector list. The following pages states that this feature needs to be enabled in the app itself:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

However, I have no idea where to include:
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

since meteor handles the entire build process

Comment: I don't remember having to change anything in order to make inspection work using `meteor run android ...`, although I did not try to inspect a signed production version.